# load markers data using loadGeoJson

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am loading markers from a JSON file ([located here](https://api.myjson.com/bins/tz9ze)):

```
 map.data.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/tz9ze');
```

What I am trying to achieve:

1. load `name` from the json node `properties` and display it as a title.
2. load `icon` from the json node `properties` and display it as the marker icon.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Style function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#style_geojson_data) (from the documentation):

> **Declarative style rules**
>   If you want to update the style of a large number of overlays, such as markers or polylines, you typically have to iterate through each overlay on your map and set its style individually. With the Data layer, you can set rules declaratively and they will be applied across your entire data set. When either the data, or the rules, are updated, the styling will be automatically applied to every feature. You can use a features properties to customize its style.

Like this:

```
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
  return {
    icon: feature.getProperty("icon"),
    title: feature.getProperty("name")
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tbw315xp/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

JSON data:

```
//JSON file content:
var geoJson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [35.29182, 32.917633]
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "Adrian",
      "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/mechanic.png"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [35.0611, 33.2815]
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "Chase",
      "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/mechanic.png"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [34.8621, 33.0613]
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "Lincoln",
      "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/mechanic.png"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [35.1551, 33.2527]
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "Jayden",
      "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/mechanic.png"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [34.9047, 33.0816]
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "Cameron",
      "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/mechanic.png"
    }
  }]
};
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: 33.2815,
      lng: 35.0611
    }
  });

  // Load GeoJSON.
  map.data.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/tz9ze');

  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    return {
      icon: feature.getProperty("icon"),
      title: feature.getProperty("name")
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```